# Next.js load audio from url for wavesurfer on the client side

Tags: reactjs, next.js, xmlhttprequest, web-audio-api, wavesurfer.js

I want to be able to listen to and render audio peaks using wavesurfer.js, but when I load the url from an external source, the waveform loads as a flat line. I tested using the same audio file by downloading it and saving it in my public/static assets folder, so I know wavesurfer is capable of rendering peaks, both for this file and in my app as is, as long as the url is taking advantage of next.js static asset serving.

I think it might be an xhr issue, but am feeling pretty lost even after poring over the wavesurfer and nextjs docs.

The reason I think it may be an xhr issue is the fact that I haven't been able to get any audio to render when using the external url unless I specify the backend to MediaElement in the wavesurfer init options.

Options that render waveform from the file fetched from the public/assets folder:

```
 waveform.current = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: "#waveform",

  waveColor: "#8D86C9",
  progressColor: "#242038",

  normalize: true,
  hideScrollbar: true,

});
```

[when it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVGsz.png)

and what I have to add to get a flat line loading from an external url

```
waveform.current = WaveSurfer.create({
  container: "#waveform",
  backend: 'MediaElement',
  waveColor: "#8D86C9",
  progressColor: "#242038",
  normalize: true,
  hideScrollbar: true,

});
```

and what that looks like... :/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ3qL.png)

Wavesurfer.js is a client-side library, so to get any of this to work, the waveform component is being loaded dynamically by next/dynamic.

```
const Waveform = dynamic(() => import('./Waveform'), {ssr: false})
```

Thee resulting functionality I am aiming for is rendering waveforms from external urls that I am getting from an external api, so having files downloaded to the public folder isn't really an option.

EDIT---

Just want to add that a basic html  element is able to load and play audio from the same url that wavesurfer is getting blocked by cors from

--
thank you @juliomalves, for the suggestion to provide a [mwe/reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

<s>stack blitz here</s> thts broken i guess... codeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-firefly-i6pyzw?file=/src/components/Songs.tsx

or if you prefer to reproduce locally, git repo here -
https://github.com/heresy0-0y/wavesurfer-nextjs/tree/main/client

Comment: stackblitz.com/github/mklikrrbz?file=src/components/… url is passed to waveform through the songs component. right now it's passing the static file path, the external url is commented out right next to "testStatic" @juliomalves

Comment: It doesn't look like the server where you're trying to play the audio from has CORS enabled. That's required for Wavesurfer to load the audio track and draw its waveform.

Comment: @juliomalves but why is a basic html audio tag able to load the audio track if theres a cors issue?  https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-firefly-i6pyzw?file=/src/components/Songs.tsx

Comment: It's not the playback that causes the CORS issue, it's Wavesurfer fetching the audio track to generate the waveform for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using cors-anywhere to proxy wavesurfers requests

https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere